# Function to replace in delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm making a function that replaces letters for others, the problem is that it does not work as I want.

Source

```
function encode(texto:string): string;

var
  cadena: string;
  i: integer;

const
  letras: array [1 .. 26] of string = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z');
const
  in_letras: array [1 .. 26] of string =
    ('z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'm', 'l',
    'k', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a');

begin


    for i := Low(letras) to High(letras) do
    begin
      texto := StringReplace(texto, letras[i], in_letras[i],[rfReplaceAll]);
    end;


Result := texto;

end;

Edit2.Text := encode(Edit1.Text);
```

Use the function encode () returns in Edit1 and I Edig1, which should not happen because I did something wrong when the replacement function

Comment: You can't replace chars this way. Consider what happens if you replace e.g. `d` -> `w` and then by that iteration go to `w`. It turns already changed `w` back to `d`.

Comment: either that, or you need to work with a 2nd string (different to the passed-in variable) and then assign that to result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest straight to the point solution is a double loop:

```
function encode(texto: string): string;
var
  I, J: Integer;
const
  letras: array [1 .. 26] of Char = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z');
const
  in_letras: array [1 .. 26] of Char =
    ('z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'm', 'l',
    'k', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a');
begin
  for J := 1 to length(texto) do
    for I := Low(letras) to High(letras) do
    begin
      if texto[J] = letras[I] then
      begin
        texto[J] := in_letras[I];
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  Result := texto;
end;
```

Comment: +1. I'm not sure that this method is the most efficient, but it answers the OP's intention: "function that replaces letters for others". if the `in_letras` is random/shuffled this method will work as well.

Comment: Sigh. Whatever happened to logic, reasoning and arithmetic. Also, you access the string's non-existent 0-th element. Expect corruption for exceptionally long strings (!!) and access violation for empty string.

Comment: David, Fixed the non-existend-0th element bug (thanx for the code review). Wrote the code so its easy and to the point, one could possibly write a more optimized piece of code, but this piece could also be read and understanded by new or non-programmers. Which was the point of my post.

Answer (score 6):

It does not work because you are progressively destroying the input in the loop. Each time around the loop you operate on the modified string rather than operating on the original input string.

The basic problem is that once you have processed a character, you must not process it again. You must process each input character once only. You process each character 26 times. Your approach can never be fixed.

You would be better with something like this:

```
function encode(const input: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := input;
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do 
    if (Result[i]>='a') and (Result[i]<='z') then
      Result[i] := Chr(ord('a') + ord('z') - ord(Result[i]));
end;
```

Your function implements the following mapping:

```
a -> z
b -> y
c -> x
....
y -> b
z -> a
```

The ordinal value of `b` is one more than that of `a`. And the ordinal value of `c` is one more than `b`. And so on. So the ordinal value of `z` is 25 more than `a`.

So, let us suppose that the ordinal of `a` is 0, the ordinal of `b` is 1 and so on. Then we are mapping 0 to 25, 1 to 24, 2 to 23 and so on. If that were so then the function we needed would be:

```
output = 25 - input
```

or perhaps you might write it like this:

```
output = ord('z') - input
```

Now, as it happens, the ordinal value of `a` is not equal to `0`. So in order to make this function work we need to shift the values to allow for the ordinal value of `a`. So the function becomes:

```
output = ord('a') + ord('z') - input
```

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan but your solution is hard to understand me, so I wanted to ask how I can use your code with the arrays designed.

Comment: Not hard to understand. convert 26 to 1, 25 to 2, 24 to 3, ... 2 to 25, 1 to 26. You could do it with a lookup table if you wanted. Anyway, if you don't like my solution, you can go back to yours if you prefer.

Comment: ok, you're right, I hope I do not bother you, but as the decode your code I mean that it return back

Comment: Please ask that question again. I don't understand. Are you asking for a decode as well as an encode? Well, same function does both. Surely you can work that out yourself. You just need to think about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan.